# Does Citrix XenApp working on Windows 7 64 Bit?

Tags: citrix

I've been trying to get the Citrix XenApp client going - but as soon as it connects it crashes on Windows 7 64bit. Citrix support has 0 information on Windows 7, so I'm curious if others have gotten it to work, of it's just me.

thx.

CDViewer has stopped working

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: cdviewer.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.2.0.31560
  Problem Signature 03: 4aac18be
  Problem Signature 04: DesktopViewer
  Problem Signature 05: 11.2.0.31560
  Problem Signature 06: 4aac18ba
  Problem Signature 07: 105
  Problem Signature 08: 80
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.InvalidDataException
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

It has something to do with the version of Citrix that we're using on the server vs. the latest client version.

The workaround is rather simple, in Windows 7 you need to associate the ".ica" extension with C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfica32.exe program.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hotfix for this, it has to do with the size of the Terminal Server public key, see 
[Citrix ICA clients may crash when they are connecting to a Windows Server 2008-based terminal server that has Citrix Presentation Server installed](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/949914/en-US)